# group by every 10 minutes and also get 'captureTime' for min/max values

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
chan1   |chan2  |chan3  | captureTime           |id
-----------------------------------------------------------
20      |21     |25     | 2011-10-11 00:00:00   |1
-----------------------------------------------------------
21      |5      |7      | 2011-10-11 00:01:00   |1
-----------------------------------------------------------
                .
                .
-----------------------------------------------------------
12      |25     |21     | 2011-10-11 00:08:00   |1              
-----------------------------------------------------------
20      |25     |21     | 2011-10-11 00:09:00   |1
-----------------------------------------------------------
21      |18     |14     | 2011-10-11 00:10:00   |1
                .
                .
                .
-----------------------------------------------------------
15      |26     |23     | 2011-10-11 23:58:00   |1
-----------------------------------------------------------
17      |14     |32     | 2011-10-11 23:59:00   |1
```

The table store chan1,chan2 and chan3 value every one minute. 
I want to get the maximum & minimum values for every 10 minutes and also have the corresponding the captureTime for min/max values.

Based on those requirments, How to write the sql query? Thanks!

**--------Edit---------**

Using mySql DB

**---Desired output---**

As seen from the DB, the chan1 reach the min value at 00:08:00 and chan2 & chan3 both reach the min value at 00:01:00 in the 1st 10 min interval. The rest 10 minutes will have the same  scenario. In every 10 min interval, the chan1/chan2/chan3 has min/max value separately. These min/max value and their associated 'captureTime' need to be returned after running SQL query.

Comment: What have you tried?  If you want to do code-by-request then you should hire a consultant.  Stack Overflow is for assistance with specific issues.

Comment: Can you please post the desired output? I think your description is not so clear. Also, please say which database this is about

Answer (score 0):

```
SYSDATE - (10/1440)
```

gives you the current time minus 10 minutes according to this : http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_date_time.html

This should be about it :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE captureTime > SYSDATE - (10/1440)
```

Comment: I just read a question about Oracle and assumed you used that too. As mentionned in the comments, it depends on your DB.